# Mutiple Contact Picker not working in Android api level less than 17

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, custom-adapter, contactpicker

I have a code to read the contacts from the inbuilt phone contacts and it displays all the contacts in a list view in my app.The user can select multiple contacts and display them in another activity.
This code works fine in Android API level 18 and above,but gives an error in the versions below API 18.

I'm attaching the code of the contact picker activity and its adapter.

[Error Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNfWR.png)

```
private void getSelectedContacts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.phoneList) {
            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(bean.getName());
                sb.append(bean.getNumber());
                sb.append("1");

                values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,bean.getName());
                values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,bean.getNumber() );
                values.put(DbHelper.KEY_INVITE,"1" );
                dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            }
        }

        dataBase.close();

        String s = sb.toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Select atleast one Contact",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);

            /**

            Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts : " + s,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            **/
            Intent i = new Intent(Contacts_main.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("NAME", name);
            i.putExtra("EVT_Name", event_name);
            i.putExtra("EVT_Date", event_date);
            startActivity(i);


        }



    }

    private void addContactsInList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                showPB();

                try {

                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null, null);

                    try {
                        ContactsListClass.phoneList.clear();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneName = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String phoneNumber = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        String phoneImage = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));

                        //String pImage =  

                        ContactObject cp = new ContactObject();



                        cp.setName(phoneName);
                        cp.setNumber(phoneNumber);
                        cp.setImage(phoneImage);
                        //cp.setImage(getResources(R.drawable.prof_active));

                        ContactsListClass.phoneList.add(cp);

                    }
                    phones.close();

                    lv = new ListView(context);
                    lv.setDividerHeight(0);
                    lv.setDivider(null);

                    lv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            llContainer.addView(lv);
                        }
                    });

                    Collections.sort(ContactsListClass.phoneList,
                            new Comparator<ContactObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(ContactObject lhs,
                                        ContactObject rhs) {
                                    return lhs.getName().compareTo(
                                            rhs.getName());
                                }
                            });

                    objAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(Contacts_main.this,
                            ContactsListClass.phoneList);
                    lv.setAdapter(objAdapter); //ERROR SHOWING HERE
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {

                            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view
                                    .findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);

                            ContactObject bean = ContactsListClass.phoneList
                                    .get(position);
                            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                                bean.setSelected(false);
                                chk.setChecked(false);
                            } else {
                                bean.setSelected(true);
                                chk.setChecked(true);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {

                 //   e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Crash",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                hidePB();

            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }
```

Adapter Class:

```
Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ContactObject> mainDataList = null;
    private List<ContactObject> mainInviteesList = null;
    private ArrayList<ContactObject> arraylist;
    private DbHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;


    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<ContactObject> mainDataList) {

        mContext = context;

        this.mainDataList = mainDataList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ContactObject>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(mainDataList);
        mHelper=new DbHelper(context);



    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView number;
        protected CheckBox check;
        protected ImageView image;
        protected EditText invitees;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mainDataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactObject getItem(int position) {
        return mainDataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
            holder.number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno);

            holder.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);

            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactimage);

            holder.invitees = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editInvites);

            view.setTag(holder);
            view.setTag(R.id.contactname, holder.name);
            view.setTag(R.id.contactno, holder.number);
            view.setTag(R.id.contactcheck, holder.check);
            view.setTag(R.id.editInvites, holder.invitees);

            holder.check
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton vw,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            int getPosition = (Integer) vw.getTag();
                            mainDataList.get(getPosition).setSelected(
                                    vw.isChecked());
                    /**        

                            dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                            values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,mainDataList.get(getPosition).getName());
                            values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,mainDataList.get(getPosition).getNumber());
                            values.put(DbHelper.KEY_INVITE,"1" );
                            dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);


                    dataBase.close();

                    **/

                        }
                    });

           // holder.invitees.addTextChangedListener(watcher);


        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.check.setTag(position);
        //holder.invitees.setTag(position);

        holder.name.setText(mainDataList.get(position).getName());
        holder.number.setText(mainDataList.get(position).getNumber());




        if(getByteContactPhoto(mainDataList.get(position).getImage())==null){
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.prof_active);
        }else{
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(getByteContactPhoto(mainDataList.get(position).getImage()));
        }



        holder.check.setChecked(mainDataList.get(position).isSelected());

        return view;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mainDataList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            mainDataList.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (ContactObject wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    mainDataList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Bitmap getByteContactPhoto(String contactId) {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactId));
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                        new String[] {Contacts.Photo.DATA15}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream( new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
        }

}
```

Comment: from where are you using this code?

Comment: we found a link in another stack thread Link:http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-create-multi-select-listview-android-with-custom-adapter/